# Parsing and Modyfying the html with BeautifulSoup or lxml. Surround a text with some html tag which is directly under the <body> tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm working in Python2.7 as a beginner. I want to parse and modify some html file. For this I'm using Beautiful Soup and lxml is also one option. Now the problem is Can I surround a text with some html tag by modifying the html. The text is directly under the 'body' tag , So what ever text is directly under the body tag I want to modify the html so that I can get the text under my desired tag. So I can parse it and find out the location of this text easily.

```
<html><body>
<b>List Price:</b>
<strike>$150.00</strike><br />
<b>Price</b>
$117.80<br />
<b>You Save:</b>
$32.20(21%)<br />
<font size="-1" color="#009900">In Stock</font>
<br />
<a href="/gp/aw/help/id=sss/ref=aw_d_sss_shoes">Free Shipping</a>
<br/>
Ships from and sold by Amazon.com<br />
Gift-wrap available.<br /></body></html>
```

So here In this example I want to surround the text '$117.80' and '$32.20' with some user html tag. How can I achieve this with Beautifulsoup or lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to surround `tail` text, and I would choose [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) better that [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) to handle them. The following script searches for any `element` that contains `tail` text, creates a new `<div>` tag (choose yours) and inserts it there. It uses a regular expression to check that the text seems a price and this way skips the text in the end of `Ships from and sold by Amazon.com` or `Gift-wrap available.`:

```
from lxml import etree
import re

tree = etree.parse('htmlfile')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter('*'):
    if elem.tail is not None and elem.tail.strip() and re.search('\$\d+', elem.tail):
        e = etree.Element('div')
        e.text = elem.tail
        elem.tail = ''
        elem.addnext(e)

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

It yields:

```
<html><body>
<b>List Price:</b>
<strike>$150.00</strike><br/>
<b>Price</b><div>
$117.80</div><br/>
<b>You Save:</b><div>
$32.20(21%)</div><br/>
<font size="-1" color="#009900">In Stock</font>
<br/>
<a href="/gp/aw/help/id=sss/ref=aw_d_sss_shoes">Free Shipping</a>
<br/>
Ships from and sold by Amazon.com<br/>
Gift-wrap available.<br/></body></html>
```

Comment: I'm satisfied with your answer. But here it's 'br' tag that's why you are thinking only of the tail text. So lets say there is no 'br' tag then what will be my approch.

Comment: @Vik: It's the same. Those text nodes out of any element is considered `tail` text and handles them the same way.